# How to get specific week's Saturday date when week doesn't start with Monday?

Tags: php, date

As the title says, I'd like to get in PHP last week's Saturday date and current week's Saturday date with the constraint of a week starting with Saturday instead of Monday.

I first used `strtotime('saturday last week')` and `strtotime('saturday this week')` or `new DateTime("saturday last week")` and `new DateTime("saturday this week")` but it obviously doesn't give the expected result as the week starts with Monday.

So for example, if today is 2024-03-04, the result should be :

- last Saturday: 2024-02-24
- this Saturday: 2024-03-02

What would be the simplest way to do that?

**EDIT:** To make it simple, I'm trying to get the first day of the current and previous week for weeks that start with Saturday.

Comment: `echo json_encode(["today" => date("Y-m-d l"), "last_saturday" => (new DateTime("last saturday"))->format("Y-m-d l"), "next_saturday" => (new DateTime("next saturday"))->format("Y-m-d l")]), PHP_EOL;` works for me. `{"today":"2024-03-04 Monday","last_saturday":"2024-03-02 Saturday","next_saturday":"2024-03-09 Saturday"}` But this can depend on your timezone or if today is actually a Saturday or not.

Comment: No matter if the week starts on Sunday or Monday, this week's Saturday will always be in the future, and last week's Saturday will be just a few days before, unless today is Saturday. It looks like you're looking for the past 2 Saturdays

Comment: @piotrekkr in fact and as stated in my question, the expected "last Saturday" should be **2024-02-24** and "this Saturday" **2024-03-02**. The results you had are the same for me except that PHP is considering Monday as the first day of the week so it changes everything. If you consider Saturday as the first day of the week, you would get the results I mentioned.

Comment: @aynber Well not really. If the week starts with Saturday and considering today's date (2024-03-04), Saturday of current's week is **2024-03-02** and last week's Saturday is **2024-02-24**. If the week starts with Monday then current's week Saturday is **2024-03-09** and last week's Saturday is **2024-03-02**

Comment: @KlaxCuy But by default, PHP starts the week with Monday. See [the changelog here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). You can change it with the [IntlCalendar](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlcalendar.setfirstdayofweek.php), thought I don't know if that's only for IntlCalendar functions

Comment: @KlaxCuy I'm not native speaker so I get confused sometimes about this / next / last <day of week>. For me saying next (or this) <day of week> means first occurrence of this day after current day. Same for before, it would be first occurrence before current day. If today is Monday then next Saturday means today plus 5 days and last Saturday is today minus 2 days. But after reading [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/linguistics/comments/tacgmm/this_saturday_vs_next_saturday_lingustic/) I kind of know that this can be even more confusing.

Comment: @aynber I checked it and the class is interesting. You can indeed do it by using it but it looks a bit too complicated. I found a simpler way to achieve that

Comment: @piotrekkr Yes I get you but there's a slight constraint in what I asked which is that it has to be relating to the week. So current/previous week's Saturday will be different depending on the starting day of the week

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you can use `DateTime` class along with `modify` function to find the desired Saturday dates. So logically it should be:

```
// Get last week's Saturday date.
$lastSaturday = new DateTime('last saturday');
$lastSaturday->modify('-1 week'); // Adjust for week starting on Saturday.
echo 'Last Saturday: ' . $lastSaturday->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;

// Get this week's Saturday date.
$thisSaturday = new DateTime('saturday this week');
echo 'This Saturday: ' . $thisSaturday->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
```

By adjusting the date for last Saturday by subtracting a week, you align it with the week starting on Saturday.

Comment: If today is saturday, it returns saturday from 2 weeks ago, not last week.

Comment: In fact I got a very similar solution with the handling of the case where today's day is Saturday. As Modammad stated, it won't work in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. In your example you said

> if today is 2024-03-04, the result should be :
> last Saturday: 2024-02-24
> this Saturday: 2024-03-02

But it sounds you are trying to get only the last Saturday.

To get last Saturday you can use this code: ([Test here](https://3v4l.org/W23Yo#v8.2.16))

```php
function lastWeekSaturday(int $timestamp){
    $enteredDayOfWeek = date("l",$timestamp); // get week day name
    if( $enteredDayOfWeek == 'Saturday' ){
        $lastWeekSaturday = strtotime('1 saturday ago', $timestamp);
    }else{
        $lastWeekSaturday = strtotime('2 saturday ago', $timestamp);
    }
    
    return date('Y-m-d',$lastWeekSaturday);
}

echo lastWeekSaturday(time()) ; // prints the last saturday date
```

Comment: Yes my question was maybe not clear enough and I will edit it but I'm simply looking for the first day of the current and previous week for a week that starts with Saturday. I ended up with a solution that is close to yours and Yousha one's so I'll share it and let me know if you see any possible enhancement.

Comment: I'm so glad that my code could help you. I'm sure you can achieve what you need with a some changes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended with the following solution :

```
/* Current week */
if (date('w') === '6') {
    $first_day_of_current_week = strtotime('this Saturday');
}else {
    $first_day_of_current_week = strtotime('last Saturday');
}

$formatted_current_week = date('Y-m-d', $first_day_of_current_week);


/* Previous week */
$first_day_of_previous_week = strtotime('-7 days', $first_day_of_current_week);

$formatted_previous_week = date('Y-m-d', $first_day_of_previous_week);


/* Print result */
echo
    'First day of the previous week: ', $formatted_previous_week, '<br>',
    'First day of the current week: ', $formatted_current_week;
```

Or a shorter way to do it :

```
$current  = date('Y-m-d', strtotime((date('w') === '6' ? 'this' : 'last').' Saturday'));
$previous = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-7 days', strtotime($current)));

echo
    'First day of the previous week: ', $previous, '<br>',
    'First day of the current week: ', $current;
```